# Search for text in cell and then run if/then statement on adjacent cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro that looks for a specific word ("Yes") in Column A and then if it is there then to look in column D (cell.Offset(0, 4)).  If the date value of the cell is between today (Now) and Two years, then fill in the box.  The problem I'm having is I can't seem to tie the two searches together.  I can find all the cells that contain "Yes" and I can then go to the adjacent cell in column D.  I just can't seem to get the next portion to run.

The end result would look something like the picture:

[image]

```
Sub Test_Text()
    Range("A7").Value = Now
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("$A1:$A6")
    If InStr(cell.Value, "YES") > 0 Then cell.Offset(0, 4).Activate 
    'this activates cells in column D
    'can't seem to now run the if/then statement on activated cell
    If ActiveCell.Value > DateAdd("d", 1, Now) And (cell.Value) < DateAdd("d", 730, Now) Then cell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
    Next cell
    Range("A7").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: But the values in column A are not dates. Should `cell.Value) < DateAdd("d", 730, Now)` be referring to `activecell`?

Comment: And you can dispense with activating and just refer to `cell.Offset(0, 4)`.

Comment: "But the values in column A are not dates. Should cell.Value) < DateAdd("d", 730, Now) be referring to activecell?" I am referring to the cells in column D which are dates

Comment: `Cell.offset(0, 4)` is column E, not D. You might also want to use year ("yyyy") interval in `DateAdd` as there are actually 365.25 days in a year, you'll eventually start getting bad results, possibly.

Comment: also realize that `Instr` is probably defaulted to be case sensitive, ie `"YES" <> "Yes"`

Comment: OK fixed the above based on your suggestions.  Still not doing what I need it to do :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see comments:

```
Sub Test_Text()
    With ActiveSheet 'better to set the specific sheet ie Worksheet("Sheet1")
        .Range("A7").Value = Now
        
        Dim cell As Range
        For Each cell In .Range("A1:A6") 'No need for `$` in vba
            If UCase(cell) = "YES" Then 'case insensitve
                With cell.Offset(, 3) 'we now refer to the cell in column D.
                    If .Value > DateAdd("d", 1, Now) And .Value < DateAdd("d", 730, Now) Then .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
                End With
            End If
        Next cell
        .Range("A7").ClearContents
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Scott C. Thanks!! Magic....it worked....just had to change UPPER to UCase

Comment: Yes, I get vba and sql mixed up at times.  I fixed it.  If it works, please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: done....also figured out adding ".Range("A7").Value = Now" is superfluous